# In matlab how can someone put the values from a single cell with multiple values within it seperated by a specific delimiter in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix, delimiter

I would like display the data from only one column of a .csv file in a matrix. There are multiple integer numbers (to be precise 3 numbers) separated by a semi-colon per cel for each row. Here is an example of how the data looks like:

```
  A    B
1;2;3  
4;5;6
```

(note that A means column A, column B is empty)

The desired output would be an array in Matlab with 3 columns and 2 rows.

```
>> matrixFromCsvFile=
    1  2  3
    4  5  6
```

**What I tried:** was

```
fid = fopen('test.csv');
matrixFromCsvFile = textscan(fid, '%d %d %d', 'delimiter', ';')
fclose(fid);
```

Instead of the desired output I got this:

```
>> matrixFromCsvFile = 
[2x1 int32]    [2x1 int32]    [2x1 int32]
>> matrixFromCsvFile{1}
>> ans =
  1
  4
```

Did I really just created 3 arrays within an array? I want just one. Luckily the 1 and 4 values are correct though. This already took me a long time to achieve, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix your example just by adding a CollectOutput flag to `textscan`:

```
 M = textscan(fid, '%d %d %d', 'delimiter', ';','CollectOutput',1);
```

By default `textscan` outputs columns separately (so your data is there, just in e.g. `M{1}`, `M{2}`, `M{3}`).  Setting `CollectOutput` puts consecutive columns of the same class into a single array.

e.g. this would give me five columns in five arrays:

```
M = textscan(fid, '%d %d %f %f %f');
```

This would give me two arrays, one containing the first two columns, one containing the last three:

```
M = textscan(fid, '%d %d %f %f %f','CollectOutput',1);
```

Comment: It did solve the question I asked. I can now see that it is one matrix because it shows the dimensions of it, however do you know what the difference is between Matlab showing the dimensions of the matrix (and type) and showing all the data in a matrix itself?

Comment: It's because the output of `textscan` is a cell array, not a matrix.

Comment: Good answer.  `textscan` is an amazing function that gets faster with each release.

Answer (score 2):

Use `importdata`:

```
M = importdata('test.csv',';',1)
matrixFromCsvFile = M.data
```

Comment: This even works with headers above data within a csv file, without modification. Great!

Comment: Exactly, and also, you don't have to specify how many columns you expect (the `'%d %d %d'` thingy). I find `importdata` way more convenient for importing csv files.

Comment: These ('%d %d %d') are called placeholders. Your solution was the most convenient indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You could go on with

```
matrixFromCsvFile = cell2mat(matrixFromCsvFile);
```